# Using group by to get counts while having other uniqueness conditions

Tags: mysql

So let's say we have a table `referrals` structured with the following columns:

```
(string) referral_id, (string) referrer, (string) user_id, (int) timestamp, (int) condition
```

What I want is at any given moment, the number of distinct users for which `condition` > 0, grouped by referrer. In addition, if a user has `condition` > 0 by multiple referrers, only the most recent referral should be counted. So, if both 'Referrer A' and 'Referrer B' referred a given user but Referrer B's was more recent, only Referrer B would get the user added to their count.

I know that in order to get the counts by referrer, I would do

```
SELECT referrer, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) 
FROM referrals 
WHERE condition > 0 
GROUP BY referrer
```

How would I add in the uniqueness and most recent referral conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of querying the `referrals` table itself, use a subquery that gets the most recent referral for each user, using one of the techniques in [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1).

```
select referrer, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id))
FROM (SELECT referrer, user_id
      FROM referrals AS r
      JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
            FROM referrals
            WHERE condition > 0
            GROUP BY user_id) AS maxr
      ON r.user_id = maxr.user_id AND r.timestamp = maxr.timestamp) AS x
GROUP BY referrer
```